# Update a field in table according to value in another table

Tags: sql, select, field

I have a table - Name : Salary:

```
   Code SM SM_Desc
    4    23  NULL 
    4    12  NULL
    5    11  NULL
    5    12  NULL
    6    44  NULL
    6    15  NULL
    .
    .
    .
    27   99  NULL
    32   CK4 BLABLA
    33   242 BLABLA
    34   64 BLABLA
```

And another table - ListSM:

```
SM SM_Desc 
1   Bla1
2   Bla2
3   bla3
4   bla4
.
.
. 
99  bla5 
. 
.
64  bla6
```

I want to update the field SM_Desc in the salary table according to the field SM in the ListSM table but only for code values between 4 and 27 (included).

Meaning :
 I don't want that  the value BLABLA in the salary table will be overwrite by the value 'bla6'. I don't to change nothing in the salary table for code values of 32,33,34. 
If the ListSm not contains the value in the salary table - keep it NULL.

I wrote so far:

```
UPDATE dbo.Salary
   SET Salary.SM_Desc = ListSM.SM_Desc
   FROM ListSM INNER JOIN  ListSM ON Salary.SM = ListSM.SM
where salary.code is between 4 and 27
```

Will that work? Any more suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: *Will that work?* - Did you try? did it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the target table name again as the first table in the FROM clause:

```
UPDATE dbo.Salary SET
    Salary.SM_Desc = ListSM.SM_Desc
FROM
    dbo.Salary
INNER JOIN
    ListSM
ON
    Salary.SM = ListSM.SM
WHERE
    Salary.Code IS BETWEEN 4 AND 27;
```

It wasn't 100% clear to me if you only want to update if the existing Code in the Salary table is between 4 and 27 (as it is written above) -OR- if you only want to update if Code between 4 and 27 is present in the ListSM table. If it's the latter, then just change the table name in the WHERE clause at the end.